# How do I write this SQL statement for Posts written in last 24 hours?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop, database, mysql

Someone gave me this SQL code to count the number of posts (of post_type 'mixtapes') in the last 7 days. I tried to convert it to 'in the last 24 hours' as well, but it's giving the wrong number.

Here's his code which works for 7 day period:

```
$querystr = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'mixtapes' AND post_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 0, 30");
if (0 < $querystr) $querystr = number_format($querystr);
```

Here's my code for 1 day period which gives wrong answer

```
$querystr = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'mixtapes' AND post_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY) LIMIT 0, 30");
if (0 < $querystr) $querystr = number_format($querystr);
```

Comment: What result are you getting vs what you think you should get? I ran that query against some of my tables and came up with what I expected. For simplicity sake you can remove the "LIMIT 0, 30" from the end of your query, as you'll only have one number as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd generate the date in php using the PHP `Date` class and then [$date->sub()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php). With a few more lines of code the query will read:

```
... WHERE post_date >= ".$date." ...
```