# Count posts or custom post types from last 24 hours (or from today)

Tags: custom-post-types, count

I would like to display count for custom post types (or posts) which was published that day (last 24 hours or TODAY).
I use this snippet to get count of all posts from "posts" or from "custom post types"

```
<?php
    $numposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE (post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post')");
    if (0 < $numposts) $numposts = number_format($numposts);
?>
```

in templates:

```
<?php echo $numposts ?>
```

but I don't know how to display count only for last 24 hours or TODAY (it means from midnight to midnight)

Comment: Have you tried our search? It brings up some useful solutions, [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/display-posts-from-last-24-hours-and-order-them-based-on-most-views) for example.

Comment: thanks for your link @toscho, I use a search function a lot and this one I haven't found, I have found another one 10 minutes ago which will probably help me to achieve the same with my code above [link is here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49621/how-do-i-write-this-sql-statement-for-posts-written-in-last-24-hours?rq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own function (add it to `functions.php` file:

```
function get_posts_count_from_last_24h($post_type ='post') {
    global $wpdb;

    $numposts = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT COUNT(ID) ".
            "FROM {$wpdb->posts} ".
            "WHERE ".
                "post_status='publish' ".
                "AND post_type= %s ".
                "AND post_date> %s",
            $post_type, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hours'))
        )
    );
    return $numposts;
}

function get_posts_count_from_today($post_type ='post') {
    global $wpdb;

    $numposts = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT COUNT(ID) ".
            "FROM {$wpdb->posts} ".
            "WHERE post_status='publish' ".
                "AND post_type= %s ".
                "AND DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = %s",
            $post_type, date('Y-m-d', time())
        )
    );
    return $numposts;
}
```

And then use it in template:

```
<?php echo get_posts_count_from_last_24h(); ?>
<?php echo get_posts_count_from_today(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Krzysiek, I need to use it for 4 custom post types in one place, this should serve as a daily stats of new posts without remembering how many posts were published until yesterday, it should tell me for all post_types if there are some new posts or not, can we have the code in functions.php more general for all custom post types including posts (without repeating the same code) and template tags specific for every post_type in order to use them together?

Comment: Two notes: That could be a Transient and it should _not_ go into functions.php. It's functionality and belongs into a plugin.

Comment: @DanielFoltynek: Of course. Just modify SQL queries inside these functions. You can of course ad them as params (so you don't have to copy these functions for each of custom post types).

Comment: @kaiser: If you will use it in your theme, then you can add it as theme function. There is NO NEED to make a special plugin just to add 2 functions... Especially when other themes don't have to use these functions.

Comment: @kaiser: Furthermore... You should not break SQL strings into many lines - queries are much longer then, so you transfer much more data to database server. It's one of bad practices in PHP...

Comment: A post count is some functionality that will be reused in later themes. At least the theme should _only_ contain the layout. And about SQL line breaks: The difference is _micro_ optimization. It's like saying _"If you use `null ===`, then your're faster then going with `is_null()`"_. Yeah, its faster. On a site with 1 billion users at a time. And no, it doesn't really count up. Readability is the only thing that really matters for a Q/A site.

Comment: But I agree on your edit :)

Comment: @kaiser: I really wouldn't use plugin that will only add these 2 functions. And I bet that you wouldn't use it either. And about optimisations... Of course it's not a big change. But if you show your code, write it correctly. There is no point to teaching anyone by too simplified examples, that are teaching bad practices...

Comment: Why wouldn't I use it? I got plenty of per-project plugins. Some hundreds even. Much easier to debug, maintain, etc. Only difference is that I always add the output to hooks or filters instead of plain function calls, so it doesn't throw errors if the plugin is deactivated and the function not present. Also this would be something I could reuse in later projects.