# How to Add Custom New Published Post Counter Icon on Top of the Wordpress Site

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, icon

I have a technology blog based on wordpress. I would like it to show a icon on top of the menu bar to show new post counter for today. Just like Android Authority website (check here http://prnt.sc/ck4q62)
Am a newbie here and i dont know a lot about CSS and Function.php the only thing i know is basic wordpress editing skills. 
I've tried google about it, but without any luck at all.

Any ideas on how to do it or the function.php file i can add in my theme child theme am using [bunchy](http://bunchy.bringthepixel.com/) wordpress theme)

Thanks in Advance You For Your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out code below. 
Function returns a number of posts published with todays date. You just have to modify a navigation a little bit to add this number counter to a menu bar.

```
echo "<h1>Today is: " . date("Y-m-d") . "</h1>";

function published_today() {
  $counter = 0;
  $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts'=>-1));
  foreach ($posts as $post){
    if (get_the_time('Y-m-d', $post->ID) === date("Y-m-d")) {
      $counter++;
    }
  }
  return "Posts published today: " . $counter;
}

echo published_today();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here [Count posts or custom post types from last 24 hours (or from today)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106383/count-posts-or-custom-post-types-from-last-24-hours-or-from-today)

The main goal would be to count all the published posts then loop through and get the ones that match the todays date.

Jason

Comment: Please include essential parts if you are linking elsewhere or just make such a comment instead of answer. Link-only answers are considered low quality, links die over time.