# Count Number of Posts in Taxonomy Term in Last 24 Hours

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, count

if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated, been trying to get this done on and off for a long time and just can't get there.

I am using the function below in a loop to count posts within a taxonomy name. Function below works fine, but would it be possible to refine the function further to only count posts that were published within the last 24 hours? I found a similar questions but couldn't get it to work with get_term_by [Count posts or custom post types from last 24 hours (or from today)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106383/count-posts-or-custom-post-types-from-last-24-hours-or-from-today)

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
global $post;
$taxonomy = "news"; 
$term_name = $post->post_title;
$term = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy);
echo $term->count ; 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom `WP_Query` and count its result.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'news',
            'terms' => $term_name,
            'fields' => 'name'
        ]
    ],
    'date_query' => [
        [
            'after' => '24 hours ago'
        ]
    ]
]);
$number_of_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

### Edit

I removed `posts_per_page` argument, as @birgire suggests, that `found_posts` offers total number of posts regardless of pagination.

Comment: No need to fetch so many posts, better to fetch a single post and use the found_posts property.

Comment: @birgire Thanks, I did not know, that `found_posts` show total result regardless of pagination! I will update my answer.